# Maintaining a bank account in the UK

Tags: visas, schengen, uk

We lived in the UK for 2 years and then, returned to our country before our student and dependent visas expired. Before coming back, we surrendered our NHS registrations. However, the bank accounts we opened while we were there, were a grey area for us. We had a good credit repute going so we still operate those accounts although we are no more in the UK.

Is that officially allowed? This is important especially since I wish to submit my UK bank statements when I apply for visas.

Comment: Why? Did you think that through?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: `submit my UK bank statements when I apply for visas` This is what @GayotFow is probably pointing to ? Why will these bank accounts be relevant ? Are you deriving income in UK which is being paid into these accounts ? If not, why do you think UKBA would accept them as evidence ?

Comment: It well may be 'officially allowed' but it looks like evidence that you may want to remain in the UK rather than your desired outcome of providing evidence of sufficient funds to sustain yourself while in the UK and strong ties to your home country (so you will leave the UK within the promised time).

Answer (score 4):

Before you ask whether or not maintaining a UK bank account is allowed (it is), you should ask whether or not it would be wise to submit statements from such an account. A large balance on a UK bank account (especially with an address that is no longer linked with applicant) would be detrimental to a visit visa application. I don't see why the you have to submit such documents to prove your eligibility for the visa. You have to show ties to your home country, not the UK.

Comment: You also have to show sufficient funds. Your credit rating doesn't really matter. Can you not just show you have sufficient funds in your home countries bank account?

Answer (score 3):

The [BBA Website](https://www.bba.org.uk/customers/personal-banking/current-accounts-personal-banking/bank-account-access-in-the-uk-for-non-residents-2/) shows 2 options available for non UK residents.

[Barclays International Banking](https://wealth.barclays.com/en_gb/home/international-banking.html)

[HSBC International Banking](https://www.hsbc.co.uk/1/2/international-services)

Maybe you should open one of these and move your funds and explain on your Visa application that you used to reside in the UK and have moved your funds to an international bank account.

Comment: Those options would not help the OP achieve their goal of being able to submit UK bank accounts during visa applications...

Comment: Like I said could explain on the application why they had their old accounts and keep copies of their statements and show new accounts with the balances in them. Those are the only options available to non residents so showing resident accounts mind end up badly.

Comment: AFAIK there is no rule which says a foreigner cannot have a UK bank account. Banks do open accounts for foreigners. All you need is a passport (visa if applicable) and proof of address. Whether or not this will help you in the application is another matter.

Comment: @greatone does the address need to be in the UK?

Comment: @phoog yes; perhaps proof of address the biggest hurdle to getting your own account. I don't believe that's a legal requirement but banks won't let you open an account without it.

Comment: @phoog The requirements are set by the JMLSG http://www.jmlsg.org.uk/ see section 5.3.59

Comment: @greatone so the OP *no longer has* a UK address; the question isn't about having one as a *foreigner,* necessarily, but as a *foreign resident.*

Comment: @phoog he can attempt to change his address to a foreign one but depending on their mood, the bank might close his account. Or he can leave the address as it is and inform the bank not to send any postal communication. Either way, there's nothing illegal about it.

Comment: @greatone what address will the statements show?

Comment: @Gayot Fow (Most) banks won't send your statements to an overseas address. I'm not sure what address would be printed on an electronic statement in that case. If he asks the bank to "hold" onto statements (or better stop sending printed copies) and other financial documents (such as cards and PINs), they will keep them at the branch for x number of days before destroying them. You can collect those documents from the branch. If he doesn't change his address and asks the bank to hold the post, the post will still be addressed to his old address even though it won't be physically posted there.

Comment: @greatone yes, I understand all of those aspects. it's more a question about optics and applicant credibility. Read the final sentence in the OP's question.

Comment: @Gayot Fow I agree. If anything a large balance on a UK bank account (especially with an address that is no longer linked with the OP) would be detrimental to a visit visa application. I don't see why the OP has to submit it to prove his eligibility for the visa. He has to show his ties to his home country, not the UK.

Comment: @greatone perhaps an answer along those lines might be well received by the community and the OP!

Comment: @greatone you still need to prove you can finance your stay in the UK in most applications

Comment: The bank account I am maintaining in a UK is linked to a mailbox in my name with my credentials, and I informed the bank of the change in address when I was leaving, of course. They seemed to have no issues doing that for me. The reason why I wish to show that account is because it will demonstrate a good credit rating and there is a lot of retail activity on that account because it is linked to a shopping concierge service that I offer to people outside the UK. All funds transferred to and from that account are via international wire transfers so it is all white money.